# Delete shared file spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-io, java-io, delete-file

Consider this, an Admin uploads a file, and some 10 users accessing that file (flv video). Now Admin want to delete that file. I am in this situation now and the file is not deleting. What is the best way to delete the file being shared by multiple users.

I tried with `file.delete()` and I'm using Apache2.0 and spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) for your IO operations.

Also, Copy the file to a temporary file and grant access to people on the temporary file. Periodically (based on your scenario) before granting the access to this temporary file you need to check if the master (original) file exists.

Comment: I used this "FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(file);" and it worked thanks